# difference between heapsize,allocated,free

Tags: android, heap-memory

i am testing my App first time **can any one explain about Heap size,Allocated, free of memory concepts under heap Tab in the DDMS tool**

```
ID  HeapSize    Allocated   Free         %Used     %Objects
1   9.383 MB    3.798 MB    5.585 MB     40.47%    70,117
```

I can't understand what is the size of the App in these three columns. I am testing App on a NexusOne Phone

Answer (score 1):

The heap size is, basically, how much memory your app has access to. The VM will dynamically give your app access to more memory as it is required. The allocated memory is the memory you are currently using and the the free memory is how much you have access to but are not currently using (HeapSize = Alocated + Free).